# Unity: Does ARRaycastManager.Raycast only works with Touch Inputs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am creating an AR application with Unity. In this application, I want to place an object on the detected planes from AR.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        PlaceObject(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
    }
}

public void PlaceObject(Vector2 touchPosition)
{
    if (m_RaycastManager.Raycast(touchPosition, s_Hits, TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
    {
        var hitPose = s_Hits[0].pose;
        if (spawnedObject == null)
        {
            spawnedObject = Instantiate(m_PlacedPrefab, hitPose.position, hitPose.rotation);
        }
        else
        {
            spawnedObject.transform.position = hitPose.position;
        }
    }
}
```

If I use touch input (clicking on the detected plane) it works fine and object will be placed on the plane.

When I try to call `PlaceObject` function with the same `touchPosition` from another controller, `ARRaycastManager.Raycast` return false and it didn't found any hit objects.

How to make `ARRaycastManager.Raycast` returns hit objects when called from function and not from input touch?

Comment: `touchPosition` is just a `Vector2` so I guess it works with whatever `Vector2` you pass in ... regardless where it came from  .. note however that `touch.position` is in **pixel space** so maybe your passed in vector is just to small (e.g. if using world space Unity coordinates)? Could you show us how exactly you are trying to call it?

Comment: I called `PlaceObject` from 2 places with the same `touchPosition`, first is working (from input touch) and the second is not working (called from another controller)

Comment: well how do you confirm it is the exact same vector?

Comment: I saved the first position and used it in the second one. Also, I print it and I am sure it is the same.

Comment: Sorry for being annoying but it just makes no sense ^^ Your method takes a `Vector2` .. this is a struct and itself has no clue whether it came from a controller, touch or anywhere else. So there has to be something else not working as expected or with the passed values :)

Comment: I think the problem is with `ARRaycastManager.Raycast`. It may have some restrictions.

Comment: Well as already said [`ARRaycastManager.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@2.1/api/UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.ARRaycastManager.html#UnityEngine_XR_ARFoundation_ARRaycastManager_Raycast_Vector2_System_Collections_Generic_List_UnityEngine_XR_ARFoundation_ARRaycastHit__TrackableType_) simply takes a `screenPoint` in **pixel space** .. beyond that `ARRaycastManager.Raycast` has no idea where this vector came from so it can not be related to either passing it in via `touch.position` or from somewhere else. I think it would really help to see your code

Comment: You can see my code with description: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MuK9aW

Comment: So you are actually never calling `PlaceObject(Input.GetTouch(0).position);` as in your question right?

Comment: I put the code in the question to make it easier to understand the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216006/discussion-between-derhugo-and-bilal-sehwail).